# ControllerAdvice annotation working incorrectly

Tags: java, spring-boot, error-handling, stack-overflow

So i'm trying to cover my project on exception side and used @ControllerAdvice like so

```
@ControllerAdvice 
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {
    
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<?> handleException(Exception exception) {
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(new ErrorResponse());
    }

}
```

and everything was good until i got StackOverflowError, because i used @Entity with onToMany fields. In this case i got response with confidential information from other entities AND ErrorResponse at the end. So i see that at some point ControllerAdvice did his job but still gave incorrect response. I got rid of this problem, but I'm very worried that this will happen again at some point. What can i do so ControllerAdvice would catch StackOverflowError too and give response that i specialized for this.

Comment: You have to find out what causes StackOverflowError instead of catching it.

Comment: I figured out the problem, but i see that annotation is working not as expected and if for some reason i would not see some other error coming there will be consequences

Answer (score 0):

It really isn't advised to handle an `java.lang.Error` but you only have to add another handler:

```
@ControllerAdvice 
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {
    
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<?> handleException(Exception exception) {
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(new ErrorResponse());
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(StackOverflowError.class)
    public ResponseEntity<?> handleStackOverflow(StackOverflowError error) {
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(new ErrorResponse());
    }

}
```

Comment: isn't is better to find out the reason of StackOverflowError instead of catching it?))

Comment: i already tried to do so, but the problem is for some reason i still get ErrorResponse but PLUS Entity. And yeah i figured out the problem, but i see that annotation is working not as expected and if for some reason i would not see some other error coming there will be consequences